# if(isset($_POST['submit'])) page refresh not working

Tags: php, form-submit

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='5'>";
}
```

does not seem to be working. I need to refresh the page 5 seconds after submitting to refresh the item amounts.

I have tried header as well but that just reloads the page before it loads

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='5'>";
    }

    echo "<td width=\"10%\"><form id=\"form1\" method=\"post\" action=\"$httpreturn\" target=\"votar\"><input name=\"command\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"useItem\"><input name=\"itemID\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"$itemID\"><input name=\"userID\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"$userID\"><input name=\"submit\" type=\"submit\" value=\"Use\"></form>";
    echo "<div><form id=\"form2\" method=\"post\" action=\"$httpreturn\" target=\"votar\"><input name=\"command\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"dropItem\"><input name=\"Item_ID\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"$itemID\"><input name=\"playerKey\" type=\"hidden\" value=\"$userID\"><input name=\"submit\" type=\"submit\" value=\"Drop\"><input name=\"itemAmount\" type=\"visable\" value=\"0\"></form></div></td>";

?>
```

Everything else on the page works fine, I just need to refresh to update the Quantities

Comment: is the meta refresh in the page head section? it won't work elsewhere on the page.

Comment: I moved it To the Head area and still no response

Comment: Full Code is here https://pastebin.com/vy4tJ8Vz

Comment: taking another look, meta refresh reloads the page every 5 seconds, is that what you want? if you just want to see the new data posting to the same page and querying the DB should do that

Comment: Hint on your structure: for a page that calls itself, first deal  with any user submissions and do a php redirect (if post) back to the same page. Second, generate data to be used in the presentation. Third, present the output in html only using php to do loops or fill in values. Following this pattern makes the page much easier to read and debug, not to mention avoiding some pitfalls.   A JavaScript redirect is not the right tool following a post submission